# Javascript/jQuery set condition before function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried so many times regarding my function below but still got no luck.

Function `getJadwal` to get all schedules.

```
var getJadwal = function(when)
{
    prayTimes.setMethod('Kemenag');
                        
    var toDay = moment();
                    
    if(when == "tomorrow")
    {
        date = toDay.add('100', 'days');
    }
    else
    {
        date = toDay;
    }
                        
    return prayTimes.getTimes(date.toDate(), [jsonStr[3][0].latitude, [jsonStr[3][0].longitude]], jsonStr[3][0].timezone);
};

var dataTimeName = Object(getJadwal()); //call the getJadwal function.
```

Function `getUpcomingSchedule` to get upcoming schedule.

```
function getUpcomingSchedule()
{
    var upComingPrayTime = null;
    var upComingPrayName = null;
    
    delete dataTimeName["midnight"];
    delete dataTimeName["sunset"];
    
    $.each(dataTimeName,function(key, val)
    {
        momentVal = strToMoment(val);
        
        if(key == "imsak")
        {
            upComingPrayName = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if(momentVal.diff(moment()) > 0)
            {
                upComingPrayTime = strToMoment(val);
                upComingPrayName = key;
                
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    
    if(upComingPrayTime === null)
    {
        upComingPrayTime = strToMoment(dataTimeName.fajr).add(1, 'days');
        upComingPrayName = "fajr";
        
        getJadwal("tomorrow");
        
        $('#test').val("tomorrow");
    }

    return{upComingPrayTime: upComingPrayTime, upComingPrayName: upComingPrayName};
}
```

The condition is:

1. I call `getJadwal` function for first time, `var dataTimeName = Object(getJadwal());`
2. In `getUpcomingSchedule` function, there is condition `if(upComingPrayTime === null)`, assume it's match the condition. Then it will send value `tomorrow` to `getJadwal` function, `getJadwal("tomorrow");`

And the issue now come in `getJadwal` function on `if(when == "tomorrow")` and `else`. First time running `getJadwal` with no `tomorrow` inside and after meet condition `if(upComingPrayTime === null)` with `tomorrow` value.

My question is, is there any way and solution to set the condition with my opinion:

```
//if tomorrow then do :
var dataTimeName = Object(getJadwal("tomorrow"));
//else do without tomorrow.
var dataTimeName = Object(getJadwal());
```

Comment: You mean like this : `var value = "tomorrow "; value =="tomorrow" ? Object(getJadwal("tomorrow")) : Object(getJadwal())`

Comment: Hi @Swati, as I explained above, `getJadwal` run 2 times. So on this both condition `if(when == "tomorrow") {date = toDay.add('100', 'days'); }else{date = toDay; }` it's always match. 1 for undefined and 1 for tomorrow.